# Refractroing: return or push value to new array value from mongoose callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

> Actually I'm not sure that **Title** of my question is 'correct', if you
>   have any idea with it, you could leave a comment and I'll rename it.

I am trying to rewrite my old function which make http-requests and insert many object at mongoDB via mongoose. I already have a working version of it, but I face a problem while using it. Basically, because when I'm trying to insertMany 20 arrays from 20+ request with ~50'000 elements from one request it cause a huge memory leak. Even with MongoDB optimization.

Logic of my code:

```
function main() {
    server.find({locale: "en_GB"}).exec(function (err, server) {
        for (let i = 0; i < server.length; i++) { //for example 20 servers
            rp({url: server[i].slug}).then(response => {
                auctions.count({
                    server: server[i].name,
                    lastModified: {$gte: response.data.files[0].lastModified}
                }).then(function (docs) {
                    if (docs < 0) {
                      //We don't insert data if they are already up-to-date
                    }
                    else {
                        //I needed response.data.files[0].url and server[i].name from prev. block
                        //And here is my problem
                        requests & insertMany and then => loop main()
                        })
                    }
                })
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
        }
    })
}

main()
```

Actually I have already trying many different things to fix it. First-of-all I was trying to add setInterval after `else` block like this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    //request every server with interval, instead of all at once
}, 1000 * (i + 1));
```

but I create another problem for myself because I needed to recursive my `main()` function right after. So I can't use: `if (i === server[i].length-1)` to call garbage collector or to restart `main()` because not all server skip `count` validation

Or let's see another example of mine:

I change `for (let i = 0; i < server.length; i++)` from 3-rd line to `.map` and move it from 3-rd line close to `else` block but `setTimeout` doesn't work with `.map` version, but as you may already understand script lose correct order and I can't make a delay with it.

Actually I already understand how to fix it at once. Just re-create array via `let array_new = [], array_new.push = response.data.files[0].url` with use of `async/await`. But I'm not a big expert in it, so I already waste a couple of hours. So the only problem for now, that I don't know how to `return` values from `else block`

As for now I'm trying to form array inside `else` block

```
function main() {
--added let array_new = [];

[v1]array_new.url += response.data.files[0].url;
[v2]array_new.push(response.data.files[0].url);
return array_new
```

and then call `array_new` array via `.then` , but not one of these works fine for now. So maybe someone will give me a tip or show me already answered question @Stackoverflow that could be useful in my situation.

Comment: by the way, even with `return data` right after `else` block I can't just main().then(data => {})` because it point me use `return` next to function

Comment: Probably problem already solved via array.push(). I'm testing it for now, but don't shy to bring you own opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are essentially dealing with promises, you can refactor your function logic to use async await as follows:

```
function async main() {
    try {
        const servers = await server.find({locale: "en_GB"}).exec()
        const data = servers.map(async ({ name, slug }) => {
            const response = await rp({ url: slug })
            const { lastModified, url } = response.data.files[0]
            const count = await auctions.count({
                server: name,
                lastModified: { $gte: lastModified }
            })

            let result = {}
            if (count > 0) result = { name, url }

            return result
        }).filter(d => Object.keys(d).length > 0)

        Model.insertMany(data)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }   
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do right now and how I want to see it. Will check and mark it useful real soon.

Comment: I spent almost a week for a first version of this script almost a year ago. It has 30 lines of code even w/o `require` and `logger`. You recreate it in 20 mins. I just re-write it and it's working. Thank you very much for this snipper, you 63k+ rep in SW community well deserved. I'll be very thankful if you point me couple of links for `async/await` practice.

Comment: @AlexZeDim No worries, always happy to help :) I suppose these two tutorials could help you gain a decent understanding of the async/await paradigm [Understand promises before you start using async/await](https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8) and [Async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with logic obscured by your promises. Your `main` function recursively calls itself N times, where N is the number of servers. This builds up exponentially to eat memory both by the node process and MongoDB handling all the requests.

Instead of jumping into async / await, start by using the promises and waiting for the batch of N queries to complete before starting another batch. You can use [Promise.all] for this.

```
function main() {
  server.find({locale: "en_GB"}).exec(function (err, server) {
    // need to keep track of each promise for each server
    let promises = []

    for (let i = 0; i < server.length; i++) {
      let promise = rp({
        url: server[i].slug
      }).then(function(response) {
        // instead of nesting promises, return the promise so it is handled by 
        //  the next then in the chain.
        return auctions.count({
          server: server[i].name,
          lastModified: {
            $gte: response.data.files[0].lastModified
          }
        });
      }).then(function (docs) {
        if (docs > 0) {
          // do whatever you need to here regarding making requests and 
          //  inserting into DB, but don't call main() here.
          return requestAndInsert();
        }
      }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
      })
      // add the above promise to out list.
      promises.push(promise)
    }
    // register a new promise to run once all of the above promises generated
    //  by the loop have been completed
    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
      // now you can call main again, optionally in a setTimeout so it waits a 
      //  few seconds before fetchin more data.
      setTimeout(main, 5000);
    })
  })
}

main()
```

Comment: I probably describe my problem with memory leak a bit wrong, it's not so bad as you think. The only problem there, old working script use `node-schedule` /10 mins instead of `setTimeout` and `server.map` instead `for of`. That helps MongoDB eats 4GB+ RAM in this 10 mins and keep it busy all the time. It wasn't a problem before yesterday, when I want to improve my project, but found only 20% free RAM for it.
Btw, you right about `promises` as I mentioned earlier I'm not an expert in it. I'll try this solution, right I after I complete my own. Thank you for you contribution!